# $USER already set when wanting to read username from user

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I made this code

```
while [ -z "$USER" ]; do
    >&2 echo -n 'Your desired User : '
    read USER
done
```

But this doesn't work because `$USER` is taken from the current user running the script, which isn't what I want.

How can I avoid this in the future for the `$USER` variable and also other variables where this could happen? Like `$PATCH` or similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lower-case variable names, or know exactly what upper-case variable names to avoid using.

For non-environment variables (i.e. shell variables), just use lower-case:

```
while [ -z "$user" ]; do
    read -p 'User name: ' user
done
```

Comment: lol so dumb, I don't know why I didn't thought about that...I guess it doesn't worth the effort to use uppercase variables in this case right?

Comment: @Freedo Not really, unless you explicitly want to change system environment variables like `PATH` etc.